# NoneType после объединения файлов

Tags: python-3.x, ооп, классы

Переопределяю сложение в классе и использую для получения в новом файле информации из двух других.

```
class File:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = os.path.abspath(filename)
        self.f = open(self.filename, "a")
        self.f.close()

    def write(self, string):
        with open(self.filename, "a") as f:
            f.write(string)

    def get_content(self):
        with open(self.filename, 'r') as f:
            return f.read()

    def __add__(self, two):
        with open(os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'new_file.txt'), 'w') as new_file:
            new_file.write(self.get_content() + two.get_content())
```

Создаю два экземпляра

```
first = File('file1.txt')
second = File('file2.txt')
```

И складываю их

```
new_obj = first + second
```

first и second имеют тип file, а вот new_obj получаю nonetype.
Подскажите почему так выходит? Нужен тип file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Б методе

```
def __add__(self, two):
    with open(os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'new_file.txt'), 'w') as new_file:
        new_file.write(self.get_content() + two.get_content())
```

нет `return`.